# Regarding Random duplication of data elements

Tags: matlab

Please consider my sample code:

```
data=[-1 0 1 2]; % data 
N=[4,8,16]; % No. of desired output columns
```

Now Create a output matrix such that:

```
out=1xN % having each element of data randomly repeated exactly N/4 times
```

Comment: I tried something like this for N=16(with some help):
data=[-1 0 1 2];
p=perms(1:4)';
r=randi(size(p,2),4,1);
i=p(:,r);
out=data(i(:))

Comment: Right now I am a beginner trying to learn the wonderful Matlab.and i was puzzling through this code for N=16, to make it work for other values of N in a single run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For N as a scalar it's simple:

```
data=[-1 0 1 2];
N=  4
R = repmat(data', 1, N); %// You actually you don't really need the '
R(randperm(numel(R)))
```